# WSS with proxy using port 443 browser client connect to websocket server on port 6001

Tags: php, websocket, laravel-8

I'm using "[laravel websocket if beyondcode](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets)" for the browser client to WebSocket serve on port 6001. but when I change the browser client request from using port 80/443 it's not connecting to the WebSocket server.

**Browser client request URL:**

```
wss://test.example.com:443/app/ABCDEFG?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.0.3&flash=false
```

code added in  tag

```
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /app wss://test.example.com:6001/$1
ProxyPassReverse /app wss://test.example.com:6001/$1
ProxyRequests off
```

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final working code that is worked in my centos.

Add this below code before the closing of <VirtualHost *:443> tag

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyRequests Off
    SSLProxyEngine On

    # Ensure WebSocket protocol is forwarded correctly
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^Websocket$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} Upgrade$ [NC]
    RewriteRule /app/(.*) wss://%{HTTP:HOST}:6001/app/$1 [P]
</IfModule>
```

Below is my pusher setting

```
window.pusher = new Pusher(process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY, {
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    encrypted: false,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    // commented this because it should be use default port 80/443
    //wsPort: process.env.MIX_LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_PORT,
    //wssPort:process.env.MIX_LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_PORT,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
    forceTLS: true,
});
```